# Display row or NULL in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm attempting to get information from three tables in one single query. I don't know if it's possible to do this... what I've tried so far hasn't worked but I also am not that knowledgeable with SQL.

I have three tables: `registration`, which holds registration information, `experience`, which holds the event selections for the customer (if they chose a dinner, lunch, single day, etc.), and `additionalInfo`, which holds additional event info such as their choices for specific workshops during the event. `registration` and `experience` will always have values, but `additionalInfo` will not be guaranteed to have values. What I want to get is, in a single query, to get the registration and event selections, and if there is something in `additionalInfo` to retrieve that, or return `NULL`.

I am trying this query:

```
SELECT registration.firstName, registration.lastName, registration.phone, experience.options, additionalInfo.workshops
FROM registration, experience, additionalInfo
WHERE registration.identifier = experience.identifier
AND experience.paid = 'Yes'
AND registration.eventName = 'march2013'
AND additionalInfo.identifier = registration.identifier
ORDER BY registration.lastName ASC
```

This query only returns values where `additionalInfo.identifier` exists, but as I said this is not guaranteed to exist.

Comment: The question has already been answered, but may I just add that "ASC" is generally not required as it's the ANSI default behaviour for ordering. Therefore "ORDER BY registeration.lastName" would be sufficient. Generally, you explicitly use ASC when you are ordering in multiple directions on multiple fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  registration.firstName, 
        registration.lastName, 
        registration.phone, 
        experience.options, 
        additionalInfo.workshops
FROM    registration
        INNER JOIN experience
            ON registration.identifier = experience.identifier
        LEFT JOIN additionalInfo
            ON additionalInfo.identifier = registration.identifier
WHERE   experience.paid = 'Yes' AND 
        registration.eventName = 'march2013'
ORDER   BY registration.lastName ASC
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using Left Join

You can also check if the database resultset returned has

resultset.eof

I always use this to check if the database returned anything